# Можно ли использовать git в Visual Studio?

Tags: git, ide, visual-studio

Я всегда пользовался Идеей. И даже для проектов, которые пишу только я, использовал git. Чтобы пользоваться удобным контролем версий, сравнивать (получать diff), откатываться, и т.д. Потому что без истории неудобно. Теперь мне нужно начать проект в Visual Studio (C#). Можно ли как-то использовать git из Visual Studio, как это есть в Идее? Есть ли какая-то интеграция этой системы контроля версий в IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YouTube "Using Git with Visual Studio"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=efS0kKvfi6k) -- вот демонстрация установки и использование git в VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [этот](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) проект